# Laravel Breeze LdapRecord authenticates if username is added to database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, ldap

My question is it possible to do that thing with LdapRecord in Laravel 8 (Breeze Authentication)?

ActiveDirectory contains a lot of Users, which cannot sign in before they didn't appear at database, so:

1. Admin creates new User like in default CRUD, putting his
   sAMAccountName in form (password isn't neccessary, it's stored in
   AD),
2. User which now appears in DB can authenticate with sAMAccountName and password which use in AD.
3. User which appears in AD and don't have created Account by Admin can't sign in.

Is it possible to do something like that in LdapRecord? How I can achieve that? I played only with basic DB Auth.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying control which AD users can login to your Laravel app, the best way to do that is to create an AD group containing the users who should have access. Then create an [Ldaprecord rule](https://ldaprecord.com/docs/laravel/v2/auth/database/configuration#creating-rules)  to restrict logins only to members of that group.

This is likely to be easier to maintain as all your data is in one place (AD) rather than having users and passwords in AD and authorisation data in your Laravel app.

Comment: In big scale company there should be an issue with that. I know that I can create a separate group in AD but with many departments, policies etc. it can be difficult.